# Which one is performance wise to clear a string builder?

Tags: c#, string, performance, .net-3.5, stringbuilder

Q :

Which one is performance wise : to clear a string builder

```
AStringBuilder.Remove(0,AStringBuilder.Length);
```

---

```
string theString = AStringBuilder.ToString();
ABuilder.Replace(theString,String.Empty);
```

---

```
AStringBuilder.Length = 0;
```

---

**Note :** I use Framework 3.5 which doesn't contain `Clear()` method.

Comment: Why not measure it an come to a conclusive answer?

Comment: Why not AStringBuilder.Clear() ?

Comment: Whats wrong in using `Clear()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** It turns out that you are using .net 3.5 and `Clear` was added in .net 4. So you should use `Length = 0`. Actually I'd probably add an extension method named `Clear` to do this since it is far more readable, in my view, than `Length = 0`.

---

I would use none of those and instead call [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.clear.aspx).

> **`Clear`** is a convenience method that is equivalent to setting the Length property of the current instance to 0 (zero).

I can't imagine that it's slower than any of your variants and I also can't imagine that clearing a `StringBuilder` instance could ever be a bottleneck. If there is a bottleneck anywhere it will be in the appending code.

If performance of clearing the object really is a bottleneck then you will need to time your code to know which variant is faster. There's never a real substitute for benchmarking when considering performance.

Comment: @just_name Use `Length = 0`. That's all that `Clear` is doing anyway.

Comment: It is correct to set Length=0 to empty a StringBuilder but keeping its memory. But when using StringBuilder.Insert(), this will not work. The Insert() will add more memory to the Stringbuilder, even if there is plenty of free memory in the StringBuilder already. If the StringBuilder is repeatedly inserted and cleared (i.e. Length=0), one gets an Out Of Memory exception finally. See my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574469/memory-leak-in-stringbuilder-when-using-insert-and-clear

Answer (score 1):

Before .NET 4:
As David Heffernan mentions, use `Length = 0;`

In .NET 4:
Other option: `StringBuilder.Clear();`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.clear.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since `Clear()` is not available for you, I think setting the Length to Zero is faster. Here are [some benchmarks](http://www.csharp411.com/clear-c-stringbuilder/).

One more [link from SO on StringBuilder performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266923/is-using-stringbuilder-remove-method-more-memory-efficient-than-creating-a-new-s).

Comment: That's what `Clear()` does: `this.Length = 0;`