# How Java do the string concatenation using "+"?

Tags: java, string

I read about the way Java works with `+=` operator, using `StringBuilder`.
Is it the same with a `("a" + "b")` operation?

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at this [excellent article](http://www.venishjoe.net/2009/11/java-string-concatenation-and.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> No. It's not the same using `StringBuilder` than doing `"a" + "b"`.

In Java, String instances are immutable.

So, if you do:

```
String c = "a" + "b";
```

You are creating new Strings every time you concatenate.

On the other hand, StringBuilder is like a buffer that can grow as it needs when appending new Strings.

```
StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
c.append("a");
c.append("b"); // c is only created once and appended "a" and "b".
```

Rule of the thumb is (changed thanks to the comments I got):

If you are going to concatenate a lot (i.e., concatenate inside a loop, or generating a big XML formed by several string concatenated variables), do use StringBuilder.  Otherwise, simple concatenation (using + operator) will be just fine.

Compiler optimizations also play a huge role when compiling this kind of code.

<strike>[Here's](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/stringbuilder-vs-string/)further explanation on the topic.</strike>

And more StackOVerflow questions on the issue:

[Is it better to reuse a StringBuilder in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242438/java-performance-of-stringbuilder-in-a-loop)

[What's the best way to build a string of delimited items in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150/whats-the-best-way-to-build-a-string-of-delimited-items-in-java)

[StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Comment: It's not guaranteed that you're creating new Strings every time you concatenate; it's actually up to the compiler. A poor-quality compiler would behave as you describe...

Comment: Not necessarily. The compiler will optimize it anyway. Change your rule of thumb to: "if you're going to use `stringA += stringB`, then use `StringBuilder` instead, because it would indeed eat heap. Your answer is more implying that you need a `StringBuilder` for every `stringA + stringB`, this is not true.

Comment: In fact it is required by the JLS that concatenation of compile time constants results in an interned `String`. Rule of thumb should be that if you are going to create a `String` in a loop and there is any chance at all that it'll loop a number of times, the use a `StringBuilder`. No point in complicating linear concatenation code with `StirngBuilder`.

Comment: Not only do String literals concatenated with + get changed to a single string at compile time (in your example, the compiler would simplify it to String c = "ab";), the compiler can also optimize concatenation with + to use a StringBuilder anyway. You should only really need to use StringBuilder for more complex appending, such as when appending in a loop.

Comment: Agree. With all of you. Just tried to keep it simple. I think the questions asks for general a general answer, an answer including cases where "a" + "b" can also be strA + strB.

Comment: @ColinD: It can only "optimize" it within very narrow constraints. For instance, a concatenation loop will result in a new string on every loop; the `StringBuilder` is not used optimally automatically. Of course, it only really matters for very large loops or loops involving very large strings.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yes, I know it doesn't do good things with loops, which is why I mentioned them as a case for using StringBuilder directly.

Comment: -1: The more I look at your answer, the more confused I get. The cases for `+` are literal,literal and something with non-literals in. The compiler can (and should) optimize the literals-only case (but doesn't in some cases, which is a compiler-quality issue) and in the other case issues a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer` in early versions of Java) internally. In complex cases (e.g., concat in a loop) it's better to write everything out by hand.

Comment: (The compiler quality issue is really a failure to take advantage of the associativity of `+` BTW)

Answer (score 38):

If you combine *literal* strings (literally `"foo" + "bar"`), the compiler does it at compile-time, not at runtime.

If you have two non-literal strings and join them with `+`, the compiler (Sun's, anyway) will use a `StringBuilder` under the covers, but not necessarily in the most efficient way. So for instance, if you have this:

```
String repeat(String a, int count) {
    String rv;

    if (count <= 0) {
        return "";
    }

    rv = a;
    while (--count > 0) {
        rv += a;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

...what the Sun compiler will actually produce as bytecode looks *something* like this:

```
String repeat(String a, int count) {
    String rv;

    if (count <= 0) {
        return "";
    }

    rv = a;
    while (--count > 0) {
        rv = new StringBuilder().append(rv).append(a).toString();
    }
    return rv;
}
```

(Yes, really — see the disassembly at the end of this answer.) Note that it created a new `StringBuilder` on every iteration, and then converted the result to `String`. This is inefficient (but it doesn't matter unless you're doing it a *lot*) because of all of the temporary memory allocations: It allocates a `StringBuilder` and its buffer, quite possibly reallocates the buffer on the first `append` [if `rv` is more than 16 characters long, which is the default buffer size] and if not on the first then almost certainly on the second `append`, then allocates a `String` at the end — and then does it *all again* on the next iteration.

You could gain efficiency, if necessary, by rewriting it to explicitly use a `StringBuilder`:

```
String repeat(String a, int count) {
    StringBuilder rv;

    if (count <= 0) {
        return "";
    }

    rv = new StringBuilder(a.length() * count);
    while (count-- > 0) {
        rv.append(a);
    }
    return rv.toString();
}
```

There we've used an explicit `StringBuilder` and also set its initial buffer capacity to be large enough to hold the result. That's more memory-efficient, but of course, marginally less clear to inexperienced code maintainers and marginally more of a pain to write. So *if* you find a performance issue with a tight string concat loop, this might be a way to address it.

You can see this under-the-covers `StringBuilder` in action with the following test class:

```
public class SBTest
{
    public static final void main(String[] params)
    {
        System.out.println(new SBTest().repeat("testing ", 4));
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String repeat(String a, int count) {
        String rv;

        if (count <= 0) {
            return "";
        }

        rv = a;
        while (--count > 0) {
            rv += a;
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

...which disassembles (using `javap -c SBTest`) like this:

```
Compiled from "SBTest.java"
public class SBTest extends java.lang.Object{
public SBTest();
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial  #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: return

public static final void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: new   #3; //class SBTest
   6: dup
   7: invokespecial  #4; //Method "<init>":()V
   10: ldc   #5; //String testing
   12: iconst_4
   13: invokevirtual  #6; //Method repeat:(Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/lang/String;
   16: invokevirtual  #7; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   19: iconst_0
   20: invokestatic   #8; //Method java/lang/System.exit:(I)V
   23: return

java.lang.String repeat(java.lang.String, int);
Code:
   0: iload_2
   1: ifgt  7
   4: ldc   #9; //String
   6: areturn
   7: aload_1
   8: astore_3
   9: iinc  2, -1
   12: iload_2
   13: ifle  38
   16: new   #10; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   19: dup
   20: invokespecial  #11; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   23: aload_3
   24: invokevirtual  #12; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   27: aload_1
   28: invokevirtual  #12; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   31: invokevirtual  #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   34: astore_3
   35: goto  9
   38: aload_3
   39: areturn

}
```

Note how a new `StringBuilder` is created on *each* iteration of the loop and created using the default buffer capacity.

All of this temporary allocation stuff sounds ugly, but again, only if you're dealing with substantial loops and/or substantial strings. Also, when the resulting bytecode is run, the JVM may well optimize it further. Sun's HotSpot JVM, for instance, is a very mature JIT optimizing compiler. Once it's identified the loop as a hot spot, it may well find a way to refactor it. Or not, of course. :-)

My rule of thumb is I worry about it when I see a performance problem, or if I know I'm doing a **lot** of concatenation and it's *very likely* to be a performance problem and the code won't be significantly impacted from a maintainability standpoint if I use a `StringBuilder` instead. The rabid anti-premature-optimization league would probably disagree with me on the second of those. :-)

Comment: @Tom Brito: Actually, based on the question, I'm not sure whether the one-word answer would be "yes" or "no" so I took that out and just explained what goes on. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you rock!!(I know its not a recommended comment... I could not resist :P)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's the same, but the compiler can additionally optimize concatenations of *literals* before issuing the code, so `"a"+"b"` can be just issued as `"ab"` directly.

Comment: nope they're not the same; how can they be - concatenation with immutable strings & concatenation with string builer ?

@Pablo Santa Cruz provides a worthy answer.

Comment: @phoenix24: Actually, he spouts stupid rubbish **precisely** because he doesn't differentiate between literal concatenation and non-literal concat.

Answer (score 4):

For concatenating a fixed number of strings **in one expression** with `+`, the compiler will produce code using a single `StringBuilder`.

E.g. the line

```
String d = a + b + c;
```

results in the same bytecode as the line

```
String d = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).append(c).toString();
```

when compiled using the javac compiler. (The Eclipse compiler produces somewhat more optimized code by invoking `new StringBuilder(a)`, thus saving one method call.)

As mentioned in other answers, the compiler will concatenate string literals like `"a" + "b"` into one string itself, producing bytecode that contains `"ab"` instead.

As mentioned everywhere on the net, you should not use `+` to build up one string **within a loop**, because you are copying the beginning of the string over and over to new strings. In this situation you should use one `StringBuilder` which you declare outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> `"a" + "b"` operation

Though readable, easy to format and straight forward, concatenating strings with "+" is considered to be bad in Java.

Each time you append something via '+' (String.concat()) a new String  is created, the old String content is copied, the new content is appended, and the old String is discarded. The bigger the String gets the longer it takes - there is more to copy and more garbage is produced.
**Note:** if you are just concatenating a few (say 3,4) strings and not building a string via a loop or just writing some test application, you could still stick with "+"

> Using `StringBuilder`

When performing extensive String manipulation (or appending through a loop), replacing "+" with `StringBuilder`.append is likely recommended. The intermediate objects mentioned in case of "+" are not created during `append()` method call.

Also to be noted that optimizations in the Sun Java compiler, which automatically creates `StringBuilders` (`StringBuffers` < 5.0) when it sees String concatenations. But that is just Sun Java compiler.

Answer (score -2):

> Strings are more commonly concatenated
>    with the + operator, as in 
>   `"Hello," + " world" + "!"`

[Source](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: Yes, but I think he means, how does the compiler do that operation. (And the answer is indeed that it uses a `StringBuilder` under-the-covers.)