# Question Mark in a Box when using println

Tags: java, println

When running this in a command prompt,

```
System.out.println(Num + " is prime!");
System.out.println("Press N to put in another number or S to stop");
```

Where `Num` is an `int`

This is what comes out:

[image: This is what comes out]

Is there any way to counter it or should I just deal with it?

Comment: Looks like an **encoding** issue to me. what is `Num`? Is it an `int` or rather a `String`? Where does it come from?

Comment: What is `Num`? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Usually you get this when trying to print out Unicode characters, what is the type of `Num`?

Comment: Num is an `int`

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(Num) + " is prime!");
```

Edit: Adding more information to replete the mystery here.

java.lang.String.valueOf will correctly parse your Number where as simply adding a Number with a String will vary between compilers.

See  more here [Concat an integer to a String - use String literal or primitive from performance and memory point of view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782804/concat-an-integer-to-a-string-use-string-literal-or-primitive-from-performance)

Comment: Where's the `?` coming from and why does this fix it?

Comment: "...simply adding a Number with a String will vary between compilers." -- Say what? No, it won't.