# how to replace string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a `String str = "a_bcde_fghij_k"`.

and I want to change it to `"aBcdeFghijK"`

If have a `_` character, the next character will be change to uppercase and remove `_` character.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace special characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: @AdamArold: I don't see how it's a duplicate of that at all. What part of that deals with "upper-case the next letter"?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when there are two underscores (like "__a")?

Comment: You'll need the Character.toUpperCase(char); command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect you'll need to just go through this character by character, building up the string as you go. For example:

```
public static String underscoreToCapital(String text) {
    // This will be a bit bigger than necessary, but that shouldn't matter.
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    boolean capitalizeNext = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c == '_') {
            capitalizeNext = true;
        } else {
            builder.append(capitalizeNext ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c);
            capitalizeNext = false;
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think regexes give much simpler code, but probably a slower one.

Comment: Oh btw it's `text.length()` ;)

Comment: @m0skit0: Fixed, thanks. But I still prefer this over the regex version :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok I understand :) But I've learned a lesson: never waste my time again writing answers when you answer xD Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @JonSkeet +10 upvotes and accepted... but this is not working. Did anyone try this? For input `a_acde_fghij_k` it returns `AaCDEfGHIJk`, which as I understood the question, is wrong. This `capitalizeNext ? c : Character.toUpperCase(c)` looks like swapped up.

Comment: @m0skit0: No, you were right - I just had a typo. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: If you change `if(c == '_')` to `if(c == '_' && !capitalizeNext)`, you gain implicit support for escaping.

Comment: @Brian: Given that that wasn't in the specification, I wouldn't want to do it at the moment...

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions alone can't do that (there is no "touppercase" operator, so to speak).

But [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a nice little utility called [`CaseFormat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html) that can help you:

```
String result = CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, str)
```

This works, even 'though your input is not *strictly* in `UPPER_UNDERSCORE` format, but [`CaseFormat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#UPPER_UNDERSCORE) is lenient this way (if you want the first character to be capitalized as well use [`UPPER_CAMEL`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#UPPER_CAMEL) instead).

Alternatively, if you absolutely want to use regular expressions, you can use [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) (it has a nice example in the JavaDoc):

```
public static final Pattern UNDERSCORE_FOLLOWED_BY_ANYTHING = Pattern
        .compile("_(.)");

public static String toUpperAfterUnderscore(String input) {
    Matcher m = UNDERSCORE_FOLLOWED_BY_ANYTHING.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, useful info but hmmm external libraries... +1 anyway

Comment: @m0skit0: Guava contains so many useful little utilities, that it really ought to be a dependency of every non-trivial project (and quite a few trivial ones).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try splitting.

```
String str = "a_bcde_fghij_k"
String result[] = str.split("_");
String newstr = result[0];
for (int i=1;i<result.length;i++) {
     char first = Character.toUpperCase(result[i].charAt(0));
     newstr = newstr + first + result[i].substring(1);
}
System.out.println(newstr);
```

split() takes regex, if you feel that is important.

Comment: This also uses `String` for concatenation, it should really use `StringBuilder` (or at least `StringBuffer`), they are *made* to be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach from me but works good..

```
  String str = "a_bcde_fghij_k";
  int count=0;
  String[] splitString = (str.split("_"));

  for (String string : splitString)
  {
    count++;        
    if(count>1)
    {
        char c= string.charAt(0);
        System.out.print(string.replace(c, Character.toUpperCase(c)));
    }
    else
        System.out.print(string);
  }
```

Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no straight away way to do it with regexes, but I think using regexes can greatly simplify the task:

```
public static String underscoreToCapital(final String input) {
    String ret = input;
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("_([a-z])").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        final String found = m.group();
        final String toUppercase = m.group(1);
        ret = ret.replaceAll(found, toUppercase.toUpperCase());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's simpler, personally. (I retract my suggestion that it doesn't work, but I still don't think it's as clear as just iterating.)

Comment: Input: `a_acde_fghij_k` Ouput: `a_Acde_Fghij_K` Is this what you mean? Also edited it to match the question, I was keeping the underscore...

Comment: @JonSkeet answer edit made your comment right :) Edited it again so now it does work correctly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do think it's more readable and maintainable than iterating over all the characters (probably because I'm used to working with regexes). Also shorter code means lesser bugs ;) And your comment about it not working was definitely right, thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do probably some check on the execution of this method but this could be another idea:

```
public String replaceAndUpper(String word) {
    int charToRemove = word.indexOf("_");
    while (charToRemove != -1) {
        String part1 = word.substring(0, charToRemove);
        String part2 = word.substring(charToRemove + 1);
        char upperChar = Character.toUpperCase(part2.charAt(0));
        word = part1 + String.valueOf(upperChar) + part2.substring(1);
        charToRemove = word.indexOf("_");
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: You should use a StringBuilder/Buffer (for building the result) which are used for these kind of concatenations (provides better performance)

Comment: Yep, that could be an improvement. Btw, the '+' should be internally converted to use a StringBuilder if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Also too much calls to substring. Using `String#charAt()` is way better.

Comment: @Enrichman [You're wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721998/how-java-do-the-string-concatenation-using).

Comment: How do you split then? With charAt I can get the Character to remove/capitalize, but thenk I have to split and rebuild the String.

Comment: @m0skit0 actually they're saying that is, more or less, up to the compiler. Probably it won't use the most efficient way but it will probably use a StringBuilder. Btw, I guess it's not noticeble for a String like the one the op posted (at least in a small loop, of course).

Comment: Yes probably, but you can just StringBuffer/StringBuilder and forget about it ;)