# String Array to String

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am trying to take an arbitrary-length String[] and print it out to a String, preferably with field separators. Right now I have:

```
String[] start = {"first", "second", "third"}; //[] to convert
String cC = "";
String finish = ""; // Final String
String cC1 = "";
{
    for (int i = 0; i < puts.length; i++) {
        cC = puts[i] + ", ";
        cC1 = (finish + cC);
        finish = cC1;
    }
}
```

But for some reason it is only returning the "second" value. How can I make it properly concatenate the values?

Also, could I simplify the code by using `finish += cC`? Thanks.

Comment: Why so much of variables?

Comment: Should `puts` be `start`? Also, you should be appending to the same element and finally printing that element.

Comment: You should check out `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I was changing names when I copied it from my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[] start = {"first", "second", "third"};
String addedTogether = Arrays.toString(start);

System.out.println(addedTogether);
//prints [first, second, third]
```

Comment: If you want separators, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/java-equivalents-of-c-sharp-string-format-and-string-join

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks Steve and Ameen!

Comment: Yes, but only because the noob timers don't allow me to accept an answer for ~20 mins. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to append to a string you should use **+=**
e.g.

```
String[] start = {"first", "second", "third"};
String cc = "";
String separator = ",";

for (int i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
    cc += start[i];
    //Not Add , if it is the last element.
    if(i!=start.length-1){
       cc+=separator;
    }
}
```

etc.

with your way you are setting the last value to finish.

Comment: No, concatenation is a bad idea. StringBuilder should be generally used. +1 anyway as valid/

Comment: @hexafraction Agreed, concatenation is a bad idea, but nonetheless, why are you, @ManosProm, doing `"One" + ","` instead of `"One,"`?  It unnecessarily makes an additional `StringBuilder`.

Comment: oh yes, i thought of adding the array and i added "one" , "two" honest mistake and i will edit the answer to fix this.

Comment: @hexafraction Generally i know that concatenation is a bad idea. But his problem was that he wasn't using it the right way and instead of giving him a whole new approach, it is better to correct the mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to concatenate Strings using += operator. It is always better to construct StringBuilder object and append all the values to it. And lastly call toString() on the StringBuilder object.

Take a look at this link to understand the performance hit associated with using + operator for string concatenation. 
http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/09/under-hood-of-java-strings.html
[How Java do the string concatenation using "+"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721998/how-java-do-the-string-concatenation-using)

Comment: I believe you, but could you please elaborate why "it is a very bad idea to concatenate Strings using += operator?"

Comment: please refer the links that I have added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] start = {"first", "second", "third"}; //[] to convert
String finish = ""; // Final String
{
    for (int i = 0; i < starts.length; i++) {
        finish = finish + start[i] + ", ";
    }
}
```

(If you wanted to do all this manually for some reason...)

Answer (score 0):

Check out -- [Java equivalents of C# String.Format() and String.Join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/java-equivalents-of-c-sharp-string-format-and-string-join)

That provides a string.join method, as well as some reading on useful string utility methods.