# String Constant Pool mechanism

Tags: java, string

Can anyone explain this strange behavior of `String`s?

Here's my code:

```
String s2 = "hello";
String s4 = "hello"+"hello";
String s6 = "hello"+ s2;

System.out.println("hellohello" == s4);
System.out.println("hellohello" == s6);

System.out.println(s4);
System.out.println(s6);
```

The output is:

```
true
false
hellohello
hellohello
```

Comment: output is correct, as you can simply proove.

Comment: Here's your assignment: Compile with `javac -XD-printflat -d <output_directory_here> <source_file_here>` and see what the output is. Hint: This "oddity" is **not** caused by the String pool, although the pool is still involved. Bonus points for seeing what happens if you add `final` to the variable declarations

Comment: Why do you find it "strange"?

Comment: do you know about String.equals ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [whats the difference between ".equals and =="](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Answer (score 6):

You need to be aware of the difference between `str.equals(other)` and `str == other`. The former checks if two strings have the same content. The latter checks if they are the *same object*. `"hello" + "hello"` and `"hellohello"` can be optimised to be the same string at the compilation time. `"hello" + s2` will be computed at runtime, and thus will be a new object distinct from `"hellohello"`, even if its contents are the same.

EDIT: I just noticed your title - together with user3580294's comments, it seems you should already know that. If so, then the only question that might remain is why is one recognised as constant and the other isn't. As some commenters suggest, making `s2` final will change the behaviour, since the compiler can then trust that `s2` is constant in the same way `"hello"` is, and can resolve `"hello" + s2` at compilation time.

Answer (score 5):

```
String s2 = "hello";
String s4 = "hello" + "hello"; // both "hello"s are added and s4 is resolved to "hellohello" during compile time (and will be in String pool)
String s6 = "hello"+ s2; // s6 is resolved during runtime and will be on heap (don't apply Escape analysis here)
```

So,

```
System.out.println("hellohello" == s4); // true
System.out.println("hellohello" == s6);  // false
```

Answer (score 5):

`"hello" + s2` works like this:

- An instance of the [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class is created (behind the scenes)
- The `+` operator actually invokes the [StringBuilder#append(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) method
- When the appending is done, a [StringBuilder.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString()) method is invoked, which returns a brand new String object. This is why `"hellohello" == s6` is actually `false`.

More info:

- [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [How Java do the string concatenation using “+”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721998/how-java-do-the-string-concatenation-using)

Answer (score 2):

String `s4` is interned and reference to this string and to "hellohello" is the same.
Because of that you get `true` on the line:

```
System.out.println("hellohello" == s4);
```

String `s6` is not interned, it depends on a ***variable*** `s2`. And references to "hellohello" and to string `s6` are not equal. Because of that you get `false` on the line:

```
System.out.println("hellohello" == s6);
```

But if you declare `s2` as **final**, which makes `s2` constant, you will get `true` instead of `false` on the line `System.out.println("hellohello" == s6);`, because now compiler can intern the string `s6`, as it depends on constant values, and the references to "hellohello" and to `s6` will be equal to each other.