# Java CLI Application performance with StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, performance

**General:**
I am writing a socket client that receives "Market" data/quotes all the time (never ending loop) from some server side (distant one).
i am dividing the data in to chunks so i can use it.
each chunk contains about 200 characters and needs to be converted in to an array.
After a chunk was divided it is been parsed in to a List (No Problems here).

**The problem:**
The CPU usage is reaching to 40% after 10 minutes of running.
I have managed to isolate the problem.
Every chunk needs to be converted in to json.
So i am giving you now the actual code that does the problems.
this code executes every 300-400 MS.
skipping this code will leave the entire system with 1%-2% CPU usage.

***Note:***
I have read this thread but i don't see any solution there.
[Is it better to reuse a StringBuilder in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242438/java-performance-of-stringbuilder-in-a-loop)

**The code:**

```
private static StringBuffer jsonVal = new StringBuffer();

    public static String toJson(List<QuotesData> quotesData) {
        // Empty variable
        jsonVal.delete(0, jsonVal.length());
        jsonVal.append("{");
        synchronized (quotesData) {
            for (QuotesData quote : quotesData) {

                jsonVal.append("\"").append(quote.getSymbol()).append("\":[{");
                jsonVal.append("\"ask\":\"").append(quote.getAsk()).append(
                        "\",");
                jsonVal.append("\"bid\":\"").append(quote.getBid()).append(
                        "\",");
                jsonVal.append("\"time\":\"").append(quote.getDateTime())
                        .append("\"}],");

            }
            jsonVal.append("}");
            String returnString = jsonVal.toString();
            return returnString.toString().replace("}],}", "}]}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you are using (contrarily to the title, BTW) a StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder ? Do you synchronization at that level ?

Answer (score 2):

First I would suggest using JProfiler or JConsole, both included in JDK6, to pinpoint *exactly* where the performance hit is.

Without knowing where the CPU usage is, I would avoid `synchronized`.  I doubt `append` is the problem.  Clean it up by getting rid of the `static` local `jsonVal`, too.

```
public static String toJson(final List<QuotesData> quotesData) {
    final List<QuotesData> theData = new ArrayList<QuotesData>(quotesData);
    StringBuffer jsonVal = new StringBuffer();
    jsonVal.append("{");
    for (QuotesData quote : quotesData) {
        jsonVal.append("\"").append(quote.getSymbol()).append("\":[{");
        jsonVal.append("\"ask\":\"").append(quote.getAsk()).append(
                "\",");
        jsonVal.append("\"bid\":\"").append(quote.getBid()).append(
                "\",");
        jsonVal.append("\"time\":\"").append(quote.getDateTime())
               .append("\"}],");

    }
    jsonVal.append("}");
    String returnString = jsonVal.toString();
    return returnString.toString().replace("}],}", "}]}");
}
```

Consider using a JSON library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  The code becomes much simpler.  You can tweak the output if needed:

```
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
public static String toJson(final List<QuotesData> quotesData) {
    return gson.toJson(new ArrayList<QuoteData>(quotesData));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, List<QuotesData> is not clonable

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Profile the code, it should show you the hot spots.
- Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. `StringBuffer` is synchronized, `StringBuilder` is not.
- Is the `synchronized` statement really needed? If not, try removing it.
- `toString()` is not needed on the return statement. You can remove it.
- Modify the code so that you don't need the `replace()` method in the end, that could be costly if `returnString` is long.
- Try to create a new `StringBuffer` object before the loop instead clearing of the old one.
- Try to return [interned](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) value of the string i.e. `return returnString.intern()`

Comment: yes, this is a thread safe area... buy i gave it a shot... no changes.

Answer (score 0):

My guest is that StringBuilder is constantly being resized. How many quotesData there is? I suggest you create a StringBuilder with a size before the for loop:

```
StringBuffer jsonVal = new StringBuffer(quotesData.size()*200); //the 200 is on top of my head. Do a few loop to see what is the average length of a QuotesData.
```

By the way, have you considered using StringBuilder instead? It's the same as StringBuffer, minus the overhead of being thread-safe (StringBuffer is synchronized, StringBuild is not).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this looks like a classic case of over optimization.
Object creation isn't that expensive that you need to rewrite the same string buffer, especially if this is called every 300-400ms.

I'll try to address every possible scenario:
**Exponential growth**
The above code is assigned to a new thread every 300ms but the list is enormous and takes over 300ms to serialize. If this is the case you are basically choking your resources and it is only a matter of time before the application crashes.
If this is the case, you should see the CPU constantly rising.
The solution would be to:

1. Limit the number of threads that can run concurrently so you don't kill the application
2. Concurrently build the json object and merge the result so building a single json takes less then 300ms.

**Speedups**
OK, so the list isn't clonable which I'm assuming means it isn't really a list but rather some sort of queue implemented as a list interface. So leaving synchronization as is I would do this:

```
public static final int JSON_LENGTH = 250; //you probably know this

public static String toJson(final List<QuotesData> quotesData) {
    jsonVal = new StringBuilder(JSON_LENGTH * quotesData.size());
    jsonVal.append("{");
    synchronized (quotesData) {
        for (QuotesData quote : quotesData) {

            jsonVal.append("\"").append(quote.getSymbol()).append("\":[{")
            .append("\"ask\":\"").append(quote.getAsk()).append("\",")
            .append("\"bid\":\"").append(quote.getBid()).append("\",")
            .append("\"time\":\"").append(quote.getDateTime()).append("\"}],");

        }
        // much much faster than replace
        jsonVal.setCharAt(jsonVal.length()-1, '}');
        return jsonVal.toString();
    }
}
```

Most of the changes are cosmetic, and I'm pretty sure that the JIT would already optimize them. Only difference I would do is use StringBuilder and create a new one each time and don't use *.replace()*.
But to stress my point further unless you fit the first description (exponential growth) I doubt the problem is here. I would look at you list implementation first.

Comment: Asaf, thanks...
nothing seems to help. i even tried to do it an a thread pool...
the funny thing is, i have the same code in PHP and it works faster for longer time.  with no CPU problems...
any way.  
Toda...     
Thanks