# How to quickly format floating point number in Android game loop?

Tags: android, string, formatting, string-formatting

I'd like to display a millisecond timer value in a game.

`String.format` is hellishly slow on Android, so I can't use it. I currently use 
this:

```
long elapsedMillis = ...; //elapsed milliseconds
int whole = (int)(elapsedMillis / 1000);
int fraction = (int)(elapsedMillis % 1000);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("TIME:");
sb.append(whole);
sb.append('.');
if(fraction < 10)
sb.append("00");
else if(fraction < 100)
sb.append("0");
sb.append(fraction);
g.drawText(sb.toString(), ...);
```

but I think it could be done faster. Can you please guide me in the right direction? Thanks

---

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242438/java-performance-of-stringbuilder-in-a-loop)

Comment: `final` variables perhaps. Else I couldn't image more than what you have now. Is this mission critical code & did you consider to put it in a NDK function?

Comment: used static StringBuilder and final variables, and TIME: pre-drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some ideas:

- use a static StringBuilder initialized with a large capacity
- use a native function
- have "TIME:" pre-drawn (I assume it does not move)
- keep the time value in milliseconds