# Reusing StringBuffer

Tags: java, performance, java-6, java-5, stringbuffer

I'm aware of the difference between concat, StringBuffer and StringBuilder. I'm aware of the memory issue with the StringBuffer.toString backing array which can explode memory. I'm even aware of the JDK Sun optimization consisting in allocation a power of two for initial capacity.

But I'm still wondering about the best way to reuse a StringBuffer (used in toString()) or, if reusing the StringBuffer is pertinent. Which one is better with memory and speed performance in mind ?

```
public String toString2() {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(<size>) 
  ... several .append(stuff) ...
  sb.trimToSize()
  return sb.toString()
}
```

or

```
private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(<size>) 
public String toString2() {
  sb.delete()
  sb.setLength(1024)
  sb.trimToSize() 
  ... several .append(stuff) ...
  return sb.toString()
}
```

And why ?

Comment: Why in the world would the `toString()` method of *anything* be a performance bottleneck? If it is, then chances are that `String` is probably not the ideal thing to use for whatever operation you plan to do with it.

Comment: This question might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192512/how-to-clear-empty-java-stringbuilder . Another consideration would be thread safety, in the second option two threads calling `toString´ concurrently would get the wrong result.

Comment: My application is very strongly real time and multithreaded. And the toString() method is really a bottleneck because we have a deep aggregated object to log for support.

Comment: @Zofren: then maybe logging that information in a more compact, easier-to-produce, binary format might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `StringBuilder`, a non-synchronized variant of `StringBuffer` -- that gives you a performance boost straight out of the box.
2. No need to call `trimToSize` -- you are just forcing the `StringBuilder` to make a new char array.
3. You'll save very, very little by reusing a `StringBuilder` since the JVM is highly optimized for the allocation of short-lived objects.
4. Use `StringBuilder` instead of a simple concatenation expression only if you cannot express your string in a single expression -- for example, you are iterating over some stuff. Concatenation compiles to basically the same code using the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I'm in an heavy iterating recursive log, that's why I asked. Your point 3 is what I wanted to be assured of.

Comment: `StringBuffer` may be a short-lived object but it has an internal buffer which may get resized frequently. Shouldn't the builder be reused in this case, to avoid buffer reallocation (ie. with a call to `#setLength(0)`)?

Comment: @rath That's true, but it very often does not matter. Giving a good initial size reduces the likelihood of resizing. Also keep in mind that reusing the same string builder makes the method not thread-safe. A notorious example of adverse consequences of such design is the `DateFormat` class.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the first example is definitely clearer, easier to read and safer - which should almost always trump performance micro-optimization concerns. **If** you do have a performance problem, **and** you can prove (with concrete measurements) that it is caused by this piece of code, **and** you can also prove by measurement that in your local environment, the 2nd example is significantly faster, then - and **only then** - you have a valid reason to use that.

Otherwise, there is no general answer to your question. What would it help you if people claimed that the 2nd example were faster by *n*% on average, if it doesn't make any difference on your machine (either because of a different environment, or because the actual piece of code is called so rarely in your app)?

However, my personal gut feeling is that on a modern JVM (read: at least on JDK6, but possibly already on JDK5), the first example might actually be faster, due to clever GC tricks making allocation / deallocation of short-lived objects extremely cheap. Especially so if you used a `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, which has no synchronization overhead.

Comment: Note also that the second example is not thread safe at all: you can get mangled `toString()` values if you execute it in multiple threads at once.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use StringBuffer at all esp if performance is a concern.

If you can't be sure that only one thread will call toString(), I would create a StringBuilder each time.

The other problem you have is that different data types can create a lot of garbage e.g. `int` or `double` and this can reduce any benefit you might achieve.

I wouldn't recycle StringBuilder, I would just keep things simple. If you really need the maximum performance I would use a different solution like a direct ByteBuffer with a library which creates no garbage.

Comment: can you specify how bytebuffer creates no garbage ?

Answer (score 0):

Try performance testing both.  As with all questions of performance it'll depend on the context and how the methods are called.

A couple of notes:

- `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe, but in your 1st example thread-safety is not an issue as your method is not using an fields.  This makes `StringBuilder` faster than `StringBuffer`.
- Your second approach is not thread-safe, so if you have multiple threads calling the method, then both threads will use the safe `StringBuffer`, so you'll end up with a string that contains elements from both calls.
- If you keeping the `StringBuffer` around (2nd example), depending on how often you use the method, you may actually be holding on to more memory because the garbage collector will not collect the memory used by the `StringBuffer`, which could be used by other objects.