# android clear a string builder

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear/empty Java Stringbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192512/how-to-clear-empty-java-stringbuilder)

I'm adding values to a string and then displaying it in a text view, but when I refresh the page it doesn't clear the string first.
It just keeps adding to it.

Is there a way to clear a string builder in android?

What I have tried so far

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.delete(0,sb.length());
for (String s : awayScores)
{
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append("\n");
}

StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb2.delete(0,sb2.length());
for (String h : homeScores)
{
    sb2.append(h);
    sb2.append("\n");
}

 String awayeve = sb.toString();
 String homeeve = sb2.toString();

Log.v("home", "homeeve" + homeeve);
Log.v("home", "awayeve" + awayeve);
```

Comment: what do you mean by refresh the page? How are you doing this?

Comment: i have a refresh button that runs an asynctask again. i just want to know how to clear the string builder when that task runs so that each time it'll only display the values once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using  `sb.delete(0,sb.length());`

EDIT:

```
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb2.delete(0,sb2.length());
```

In the code above, you are trying to delete contents of an empty `StringBuilder`.

This can't be done.

Comment: where shall i put it i have edited my code above but this still doesn't work

Comment: When you find need to clear stringBuilder contents, you can call this method with SB object.

Comment: You are deleting content and then again appending in the loop. how it gonna work den!!.. what do you exactly want.

Comment: sorry i have found out where i was going wrong it was to do with array lists i was putting into the string builder it was them i needed to clear not the string builder but thank you anyway useful to know

Answer (score 0):

you can use setText(""); it will reset value with blank string