# StringBuilder - Reset or create a new

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a condition that a StringBuilder keeps storing lines matching a pattern from a large flat file (100's of MB). However after reaching a condition I write the content of the StringBuilder varialble to a textfile.

Now I wonder if I should use the same variable by resetting the object ->

```
stringBuilder.delete(0,stringBuilder.length())
```

OR

```
stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
```

Please suggest which would do you think is better as far as both performance and OOM issues are concerned.

Comment: For reference, the `delete()` call does a `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: You should benchmark based on your application workflow and choose what works best for you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The arraycopy is for length 0 for this example though.

Comment: I would profile both options to measure the performance of both memory and cpu usage and get a definitive answer for the specific case. Still, IMO the best option would be `stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();` and let the GC do its job.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think `StringBuilder#delete(start, end)` is still expensive call, you should do:

```
stringBuilder.setLength(0);
```

to reset it.

---

**UPDATE:** After looking at [**source code of `StringBuilder`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.trimToSize%28%29) It seems `setLength(int)` leaves old buffer intact and it is better to call: **`StringBuilder#trimToSize()`** after above call which **`attempts to reduce storage used for the character sequence`**.

So something like this would be more efficient:

```
stringBuilder.setLength(0); // set length of buffer to 0
stringBuilder.trimToSize(); // trim the underlying buffer
```

Comment: You might leak memory using this technique. If you create bigger and bigger Strings, then smaller ones, the underlying `char[]` will get bigger even though you aren't using it all.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis might be right, take a look at the source for `setLength`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.setLength%28int%29

Basically, `setLength` just nulls out old values and doesn't actually shrink the underlying array.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not talking about performance. The `setLength()` method just sets the `count` field to the new length. So if your `char[]` is of size 10_000_000, you're using all of that space for nothing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That's the main point, how can you say that we're still using that `10000000 char array` after `setLength(0)`? btw looking at source code it is actually setting all the previous `char[]` buffer to `\0` individually. Also see this answer for more details and please go through some answers/discussions there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193094/548225

Comment: @anubhava Say you had a `count` of 100 for a previous use, possibly a `char[100]` to accompany that. Calling `setLength(0)`, where `100 > 0`, ie. there is no `\0`, that only happens when the capacity **increases**.  Instead the `else` is executed and `count` is set to `0`. So your `char[]` reference doesn't get reassigned and you are left with a `char[100]` which you might not fully use. Even if it did set all the char indices to `\0` you would still might be wasting them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes I misread `if/else` condition and its clear that else part will be execute. I think `setLength(0)` followed by `trimToSize()` would be better for clearing old buffer.

Comment: @anubhava `trimToSize()` is dangerous too because it will create a `char[0]` which will have to be expanded at the first `append()`.

Comment: Yes it needs to be expanded but not sure why it is dangerous. Rather than keeping a huge buffer intact IMO it is better to expand it on demand.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know this is ancient, but is a larger unused, underlying array where the length has been set to zero the same thing as a memory leak? I mean, it will use up memory, but won't it be garbage collected eventually when the stringBuilder goes out of scope? Alternatively reallocating the variable to new stringBuilder could create a lot of deallocated garbage to be collected. Which is worse? I guess it depends on context of the application.

Answer (score 6):

Imho, I would suggest to use new:

```
stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

I've never heard about a memory leak in StringBuilder, but when you really push the limits you never know. I would hedge my bets against it by using a new instance every time.

In the worst case maybe you lose some efficiency and the gc gets a workout, but you rule out the OOM possibility.

Because of that, and also for reasons of clarity I would personally take the new approach.

Answer (score 5):

One fundamental difference is sb.delete keeps the reference, while the constructor loses it.

If your SB is a method argument, and is supposed to be used to pass content back to the caller, you have to use sb.delete. The caller holds the original reference.

Answer (score 3):

Well there's a greater difference between the two. The first retains whatever capacity it had before you deleted the characters (i.e. `stringBuilder.capacity()`) whereas the second creates a new `StringBuilder` with the default capacity, 16. Of course you could just pass `stringBuilder.capacity()` as an argument to the constructor, but it's important to understand the distinction here, nonetheless.

In any case, I highly doubt that you will see a substantial performance difference between these two variants, so choose whichever is more readable and easier to manage. *Only* when you've conclusively determined that this is causing some sort of bottleneck should you change your approach.

Answer (score 2):

It is cheaper reuse the created object than allocate a new one, always. It also avoids extra work for the Garbage Collector, as you are handling only an object.

The faster way is:

```
stringBuilder.setLength(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
 stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

because if you fill it with a large amount of data, calling `stringBuilder.setLength(0);` won't unallocate the backing array, so you could see memory usage stay high unnecessarily.

Also, it's just easier to read and understand.

Comment: Well, if you're going to use all/most of it again soon, one can argue that freeing and reallocating it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally we should use `new StringBuilder()` 
Digging a bit in StringBuilder class from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java) I get to know the following.

**Creating new object :**

```
/**
     * Creates an AbstractStringBuilder of the specified capacity.
     */
    AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
        value = new char[capacity];
    }
```

new StringBuilder() creates a new object with initial capacity char array.
Overhead here : GC will be called for clearing older object.

**Using delete :**

```
public AbstractStringBuilder delete(int start, int end) {
        if (start < 0)
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
        if (end > count)
            end = count;
        if (start > end)
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        int len = end - start;
        if (len > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(value, start+len, value, start, count-end);
            count -= len;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

**Using Length and TrimToSize :**

```
public void trimToSize() {
        if (count < value.length) {
            value = Arrays.copyOf(value, count);
        }
    }
```

Will call copyOf From array class

public static char[] copyOf(char[] original, int newLength) {
    char[] copy = new char[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}

Now it will also call **System.arrayCopy** which is a native method.
Now if you see in copyOf we are creating a new charArray again of 0 length,
and when **we try to add again data to it, it will call expand** because the **current length would be 0**.
So I think its better to call new StringBuilder()

You can see the above code on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.trimToSize%28%29)

PS : @user3241961 is write in case you are using reference of this object then new would require to set it again

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a tight loop and you will continue back in that loop after you write the data to the file, you should definitely re-use the StringBuilder. There's no reason not to and it's better than churning the GC. If you were writing this in C or C++ you would re-use the buffer.

Also, while true that the delete(...) method calls System.arraycopy, the number of bytes copied is 0 so it's insignificant.

Ah - somebody else mentioned me that there is a setLength(...) method which is the fastest way to re-use the buffer.