# How do I generate a Matrix style output

Tags: java

I'm trying to get an output of a random string consisted of 1's and 0's in a Matrix style. I know how to display a string consisted of 1's and 0's, but I can't keep on looping through it for some reason. What I'm trying to do, is that whenever the `StringBuilder` reaches the length of 20, I want to start the loop on a new line again and repeat this 100 times.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class main {

    static Random rand = new Random();
    static StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
    static int a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generatingnumber();
    }

    public static void generatingnumber() {

        for (int bv = 0; bv <= 100; bv++) {

            int random = rand.nextInt(50);

            if (random % 2 == 0) {
                x.append(" 0");
            } else {
                x.append(" 1");
            }

            if (x.length() == 20) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting to [reset your `StringBuilder` instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192512/how-can-i-clear-or-empty-a-stringbuilder) after `println`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MatrixFilm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 100;
        int cols = 20;

        for (int count1 = 0; count1 < (rows * cols); count1++) {
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < cols; count2++) {
                int randomNum = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                System.out.print(" " + randomNum);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string has length of 20 characters only once. You are not interested in whether `x.length() == 20` but if `x.length() % 20 == 0`.

For a new line you can append `"\n"` (or `"\r\n"` for Windows machine) to the string, everytime just before printing it.

Change `println` to `print` (which doesn't add new line character at the end of printed string) in order to maintain continuity between prints.

Taking all into account:

```
if (x.length() % 20 == 0) {
  x.append("\r\n");
  System.out.print(x);
}
```

However it still wouldn't be enough, for "\r\n" itself adds to the length of the string. This should work:

```
if (x.length() % 20 == 0) {
  x.replace(x.length() - 2, x.length(), "\r\n");
  System.out.print(x);
}
```

You can also - and it would be better to... - reset the string, as @owlstead has mentioned.

```
if (x.length() == 20) {
  System.out.println(x);
  x.setLength(0);
}
```

Anyway; what I presented **is not** a solution for the problem. Only solution to - probably improper - approach you have currently taken on it.