# Read data from file and return the same data in a string

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Read data from the file and return the same data in a string
It only returns the last line, how can I return the same data in the file?

File

```
    This is test file.
    This is test file!
    Test
    test file
    
    
    
    
    xxas   test
    
    fil
    
    !  test
    
    te
```

```
   import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Read {
        static String input = "";
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("Example.txt"));
            while(file.hasNextLine()){
                input = file.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(input);
    
    }
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Files.readAllLines("Example.txt"));`

Comment: You should print the input inside of the loop, not after it.

Answer (score 1):

input variable should be a StringBuilder and use append:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("Example.txt"));
            while(file.hasNextLine()){
                input.append(file.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println(input.toString());
```

Comment: If I want to clear the StringBuilder, how can I do that? I tried setLength(0) but it's not working.

Comment: If setting setLenght(0) doesn't work try the second option in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192512/how-can-i-clear-or-empty-a-stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append each line to 'input':

```
input += file.nextLine() + "\n";
```

And performance wise it might be better to declare 'input' as a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Another option is to insert System.out.println(input); into the while loop