# C# Utilizing cancellation tokens for each Task created

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I have a task method that generates temperature profiles in my MainWindow but is called in another form when the user inputs data for a lot (an item produced) into an oven and record temp every 30secs.

```
public static async Task genLotProfile(string lotno,string filename, string datch,CancellationToken token)

try
{
       //get temperature and do other stuff
       Tprofile temp = getLogData(datch); 
       
       //task delay
       while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
          //Task delay
          await Task.Delay(30000, token);
      }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{

}
```

My idea was to call this on an enter button function in the input form everytime a lot is entered.

```
private void EnterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //do other stuff

   //Call generate temp profile
    string filename = MainWindow.getTempProfileName(MainWindow.datachannel, lotnoTBX.Text);
                
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;
                
    MainWindow.genLotProfile(lotnoTBX.Text, filename, MainWindow.datachannel, token);
}
```

I also have a separate cancel class

```
    class Cancel
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _source;

        public Cancel(CancellationTokenSource source)
        {
            _source = source;
        }

        public void cancelTask()
        {
            _source.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

The thing is I will have multiple tasks running in my condition and I want to kill specific tasks with Cancel class on another output form when the user takes out the lot from the oven, will the cancellation token kill all my tasks running if I do the following

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
Cancel c = new Cancel(source); 
c.cancelTask();
```

Comment: There is no real magic to a `CancellationToken`, basically all tasks listening or polling for cancelled will cancel. To have finer grained control you would need to use more than one. Note you can link them into a single token source and have callbacks to have a more complicated structure. Though its hard to give any further advice not knowing exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: So if I put lets say I do CancellationToken token1 = source.Token; , CancellationToken token2 = source.Token; that would make it separate tokens and I can kill specific tasks right?

Comment: Although `CancellationToken` is  struct, the struct actually holds a reference to the source, so copying the struct is still giving you the same cancellation regime. you will need to create separate `CancellationTokenSource`s to to get access to separate Tokens

Comment: Why do you need CTS wrapper class if CTS is already wrapper itself? The `Cancel` class is totally useless. And finally, `CancellationTokenSource` implements `IDisposable`. Here's some [usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62611838/12888024).

Comment: Without knowing your previous question it is also seems totally odd why you have the while loop at all. It does nothing sensible here. Besides that, consider creating a class with a non-static GetTempProfileName method and a CancellationTokenSource member. Then you would have a one-to-one association between a Task and a CancellationTokenSource. Or better, use a class with a timer member.

Comment: @Clemens thanks clemens I actually think I might have solved the problem with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new CancellationTokenSource for each task:

```
private async void EnterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //do other stuff

   //Call generate temp profile
    string filename = MainWindow.getTempProfileName(MainWindow.datachannel, lotnoTBX.Text);

    using CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();                
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;
                
    await MainWindow.genLotProfile(lotnoTBX.Text, filename, MainWindow.datachannel, token);
}
```

When cancelling a specific task, you just need to call cancel() the right instance of the token.

Comment: This fails to dispose of 'source', which implements IDisposable.

Comment: @schulmaster: I've added using block. I've never realized CTS implements IDisposable. Does it use some unmanaged resources?

Comment: There is an array of CancellationTokenRegistations, each element of which requires disposal itself, as well as a volatile ManualResetEvent that must be closed.