# Why would you use a StringBuilder method over a String in Java?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

What are the benefits of using a StringBuilder method over a String? Why not just amend the content within a String?

I understand that a StringBuilder is mutable, but if you have to write more lines of code to append onto it, why not change the original String?

I'd appreciate it if someone would provide an example of where a StringBuilder would be more beneficial.

Comment: "why not change the original String?" because it's immutable.

Comment: It's very context-dependent (and under the covers the handling of things like string concatenation have changed over the years).

Comment: I actually just used string builder, it helps if you need to access a string from another thread or anonymous method and it needs to be final, so the String object becomes immutable, i.e)
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
chars.forEach(builder::append);

Comment: Try answering "What are the benefits of a builder pattern?"

Comment: @Rikayan Except StringBuilder isn't the same as "builder pattern"

Comment: "Why not change the original String?"  You can't.  Strings can't be changed.  (For many good reasons.)  A `StringBuilder` more or less _is_ a "String that can be modified."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the original string because it is immutable therefore having `String s = "";` every operation like

```
s += "something";
```

will **create and reassign new object** (probably it will also add a little bit of work for GC in near future). On he other hand modifying `StringBuilder` is (usually) not creating new object (indeed it is happening just once at the very end when calling `toString()` method on builder instance)

Because of this it is common to use `StringBuilder` when you are modifying string many many times (for example in some long loops).

Still it is common error to overuse `StringBuilder` - it may be example of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

---

Read also:

- [Is it better to reuse a StringBuilder in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242438/is-it-better-to-reuse-a-stringbuilder-in-a-loop)

Comment: @user16320675 Good point!

Comment: @user16320675: that's true, but there is a big difference between "resize and copy an array when it exceeds a certain threshold" and "create a new copy of an array/string for every single operation to it".

Comment: In many cases though java compiler can optimize the work and there won't be much difference. I believe in 99% of the situation there won't be difference. So for simple situation I think string + can be more readable without downside. If there is a complex building of string the stringbuilder also gives you better readability which is nice. I would consider more the cleanness of the code than performance

Comment: @VeselinDavidov: `StringBuilder` is necessary specifically when constructing a big string in a loop. In most other cases it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track by understanding the immutability of the `String` class.

Based on [[1](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-performance-the/9781449363512/)] and [[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)], here are some cases where each type of implementation is recommended:

#### 1. Simple String Concatenation

```java
String answer = firstPart + "." + secondPart;
```

This is syntactic sugar for

```java
String answer = new StringBuilder(firstPart).append("."). append(secondPart).toString();
```

This is actually quite performant and is the recommended approach for simple string concatenation [[1](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-performance-the/9781449363512/)].

#### 2. Stepwise Construction

```java
String answer = firstPart;
answer += ".";
answer += secondPart;
```

Under the hood, this translates to

```java
String answer = new StringBuilder(firstPart).toString(); 
answer = new StringBuilder(answer).append(".").toString(); 
answer = new StringBuilder(answer).append(secondPart).toString();
```

This creates a temporary `StringBuilder` and intermediate `String` objects which are inefficient [[1](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-performance-the/9781449363512/)]. Especially if the intermediate results are not used.

Use `StringBuilder` in this case.

#### 3. For Loop Construction and Scaling For Larger Collections

```java
String result = "";

for(int i = 0; i < numItems(); i++) 
  result += lineItem(i);

return result;
```

The above code is O(n^2), where n is number of strings. This is due to the immutability of the `String` class and due to the the fact that when concatenating two strings, the contents of both are copied [[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)].

So it may be fine for a few fixed length items, but it will not scale.
In such cases, use `StringBuilder`.

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numItems() * LINE_SIZE);

for(int i = 0; i < numItems(); i++)
  sb.append(lineItem(i));

return b.toString();
```

This code is O(n) time, where n is number of items or strings.
So as the number of strings gets larger, you will see the difference in performance [[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)].

This code pre-allocates an array in the initialization of `StringBuilder`, but even if a default size array is used, it will be significantly faster than the previous code for a large number of items [[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)].

#### Summary

Use string concatenation if you are concatenating only a few strings or if performance is not of importance (i.e. a demonstration/toy-application). Otherwise, use `StringBuilder` or consider processing the string as a character array [[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)].

**References:**

[[1](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-performance-the/9781449363512/)] Java Performance: The Definitive Guide by Scott Oaks: [Link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-performance-the/9781449363512/)

[[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)] Effective Java 3rd Edition by Joshua Bloch: [Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)